# Fixed vs Fluid in iOS as a Designer

Tags: ios, uitableview, fluid-layout

Designer here! I don't know very much about programming, so keep that in mind. 
I was wondering about adaptive layouts, fluid vs fixed designs. In one of the screens I designed, I am presenting a scrollable list of photographs with text overlay which will be clicked on to open a new page. I believe it is going to be a custom UITableView. I am designing for the iPhone 5, 6, and 6 plus. I would like the size of the images to be at a 4:3 aspect ratio across devices. This means on the 5, the image would be 320 x 240 pts, 6 would be about 375 x 281 pts, and the 6 plus would be 414 x 310 pts.

My question is, is that a possibility? Right now, there is a set height across all devices. The programmer I'm working with is a bit of a hot head and he gets angry when I don't understand how everything in Xcode works. I'm hoping to be able to talk with him about my expectations with more of an understanding of how these things work.

Comment: Of course it is possible, you can easily achieve that with autolayout via an aspect ratio constraint... [More on autolayout here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I would recommend a UICollectionView (vs. a UITableView) because that gives you more flexibility in the future.  Also, keeping the aspect ratio will work within a Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only a possibility, but a fairly basic implementation: Most IOS devices have different screen dimensions as well as drastically different resolutions: because of this, there are many tools available to the programmer to support these variations.

Truthfully, even without `autolayout` and multiple `nib files/storyboards` this problem is solvable with some basic maths regardless of target platform